# Find smallest quadrilateral from a given quadrilateral that fits a rectangle

Tags: c#, geometry, gdi, polygon

I am working on an imaging application using GDI+ in C# (VS 2008) and I got stuck with something. I have a rectangle on my canvas and a quadrilateral of random size on my canvas. I know the 4 corner points of rectangle and the quadrilateral. I need to compute the smallest quadrilateral that fits my rectangle. The new quadrilateral needs to be computed from the quadrilateral I already have on the canvas. The new quadrilateral need not be the scaled version of my existing quadrilateral, but the sides of the input and output quadrilateral must be parallel. I have uploaded an image to describe the problem.

http://www.4shared.com/photo/dufR-UeN/SmallQuad.html

Any ideas how I can go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` be the points defining your random quadrilateral:

- 1 is the segment [AB]
- 2 is the segment [BC]
- 3 is the segment [CD]
- 4 is the segment [DA]

Now let `E` (top left), `F` (top right), `G` (bottom left), `H` (bottom right) be the points of your rectangle. In your image, you have to determine:

- the equation of the parallel to 1 passing by `E` (let's call it 1')
- the equation of the parallel to 2 passing by `F` (let's call it 2')
- the equation of the parallel to 3 passing by `G` (let's call it 3')
- the equation of the parallel to 4 passing by `H` (let's call it 4')

Then you can compute their intersections, which in turn give you the lines you need.

Let's determine 1' (the other ones are similar): all lines parallel to 1 have the same slope as 1 has. And this slope `s1` is given by:

```
s1 = (yB - yA) / (xB - xA)
```

Then 1' has an equation like `y = s1 * x + b`. Since we want this line to reach the point `E(xE, yE)`, we have `b`:

```
yE = s1 * xE + b => b = yE - s1 * xE
```

and then 1' has for equation: `y = s1 * (x - xE) + yE`. Similarly, 2' has for equation `y = s2 * (x - xF) + yF`, `s2` being determined by the coordinates of `B` and `C`, idem for 3' and 4'.

We now want the intersection of 1' and 2': this point `I` has coordinates the verify the equations of these 2 lines, so:

```
yI = s1 * (x - xE) + yE
yI = s2 * (x - xF) + yF
```

So:

```
s1 * (xI - xE) + yE = s2 * (xI - xF) + yF
```

which gives you  `xI` then `yI`:

```
xI = (s1 * xE - s2 * xF + yF - yE) / (s1 - s2)
yI = s2 * (xI - xF) + yF
   = (s1 * s2 * xE - s1 * s2 * xF + s1 * yF - s2 * yE) / (s1 - s2)
```

You can determine the coordinates of `J` (intersection of 2' and 3'), `K` (intersection of 3' and 4') and `L` (intersection of 4' and 1') the same way. The quadrilateral you want is formed by these 4 points `I`, `J`, `K` and `L`.

Comment: This is the most awesome answer I've seen on SO in a month. You must hang out at http://mathoverflow.net/ +1

Comment: That was super fast Emmanuel. Thank you so much for the effort. But based on your description I tried random drawings. Check out this link: http://www.4shared.com/photo/7b0CphrR/SmallQuad2.html
How do I solve that? Thanks again Emmanuel.